# create pdf with jsPDF

Tags: javascript, php, html, jspdf, html2canvas

I have a php page in a `div`

```
<div id="content">
    ....
    <img src="link">

    <div>
        <?php echo $content1; ?>
    /div>
    <table border = 1>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $content1; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $content1; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<button onClick="generatePDF()" >generate PDF</button>

function generatePDF()
{
    var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a0');
    var canvas = pdf.canvas;

    canvas.height = 297;
    canvas.width = 210;

    html2canvas($('#estimateContent').get(0), {
        canvas:canvas,
        allowTaint: true,
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            pdf.save("Current Data2.pdf")   
        }
    });
}
```

The PDF is empty. How to generate a pdf like my div?

THanks a lot

Comment: html2canvas($('#estimateContent').get(0) is html2canvas($('#content').get(0), but the result is the same

Answer (score 2):

There is no property for jsPDF such as pdf.canvas

You could use canvas.toDataUrl() and jsPDF.addImage() to render data from canvas 
in pdf.
Code should be something like this ( with minor adjustments for dimensions of canvas and paper for pdf):

```
<div id="content">
....
<img src="link">

<div>
<?php echo $content1; ?>
/div>
<table border = 1>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $content1; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $content1; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<button onClick="generatePDF()" >generate PDF</button>

function generatePDF()
{
    html2canvas($('#content'), {
        allowTaint: true,
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
            var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a0');

            pdf.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 0, 0);
            pdf.save("Current Data2.pdf")
        }
    });
}
```

Or you could use html2pdf in addition to jsPDF and html2canvas: 
https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf

Here is an actual application on your code sample:

```
<div id="content">
....
<img src="link">

<div>
<?php echo $content1; ?>
/div>
<table border = 1>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $content1; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $content1; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<button onClick="generatePDF()" >generate PDF</button>

function generatePDF()
{

    var element = document.getElementById('content');

    html2pdf(element, {
        margin:       1,
        filename:     'Current Data2.pdf',
        image:        { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
        html2canvas:  { dpi: 192, letterRendering: true,  allowTaint: true, onrendered: function(canvas) {
            // canvas is the final rendered <canvas> element
            //if you need to perform some actions, cleanup, etc after the canvas has been generated
        } },
        jsPDF:        { unit: 'mm', format: 'a0', orientation: 'portrait' }
    });

}
```

Comment: You rcode works, but I'm using mPdf that is more simple and works fine. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user3576455, Hi, I agree that it is lot easier to setup mPdf. However, mPdf requires PHP, and jsPdf is preferable solution that would save your server cpu, memory and bandwidth consumption when generating PDF. It depends from project to project, what is more suitable :)